# FHIR Appointment search filtered by location and all its partOf locations

Tags: hl7-fhir

FHIR `Location` resources can have a `.partOf` property that points to another `Location`.

Let's say we have locations nested like this. Where each location is `partOf` the parent `Location`.

- hospital

  - building

    - clinic

      - exam room

Let's say that an `Appoinment` has an `actor` that is a Location.

How do I query for appointments at these various levels, if I just have a `Location` Id.

For example: How do I query for all appointments at the hospital? Or for all appointments at the building, etc.

Also, it could be that the `actor` Location is an ID at any one of these levels and we don't know which, at the time of the search.

I'd like to be able to query `Appointment`s filtered by whatever the current location hierarchy level it is, *and everything below*.

I know I can do `/Appointment?location=LOCATION_ID` and `/Appointment?location.partOf=LOCATION_ID`

But, is there any way to do *both* and everything *below* in the same search request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server you are using supports it, you should be able to use the `:below` modifier on the location search:

`/Appointment?location:below=LOCATION_ID`

See http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#recursive for the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like Google Cloud supports this. But it definitely seems like the correct answer. Thank you!

https://build.fhir.org/search.html#3.2.1.5.2.2.1

I'm going to mark this as the correct answer. 

What I had to do instead was first fetch locations and build a list of location IDs to pass as follows: `location=ID1,ID2`.